# SCIM not sending delete user requests after a hard deelete

Tags: azure, azure-functions, scim

Create User and update user is working as expected from Azure SCIM provisiong app.

I could not see any delete requests in provisioning logs , if user is permanently deleted in Azure AD.
I have followed the SCIM process.

Need help..

Comment: Did you check here ? It looks the same. If not please [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/6670/azure-ad-scim-not-sending-delete-requests.html) here for accepted ans.

Comment: thanks @AbhinandanBharamgunde , i have gone through the refered link , but i could not succeed in finding the Delete request under provision logs nor i could not see the user is getting deleted based upon the code written in Provisioning service Delete user functionality

Comment: Delete user request i  never see it is executed in Provisioning logs.

Comment: That's bit weird. In that case, it will be hard to get to solution without a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

identified the issue , if the account is disabled the  disable action is going to the app and patch user request is triggered. if the disabled user is permanently deleted , requests are not flowing as Delete calls. Apart from that , according to SCIM-> Delete request is working as expected. Thanks